# docker-compose setup not running in ECS

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, nginx, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I'm getting exasperated with deploying my nginx/django/redis/postgres setup to ECS. I have a docker-compse setup that is working perfectly in development on my local machine. However, the containers in ECS immediately stop after starting the task. I would be so happy to find out what I'm doing wrong here. I assume it is the nginx config, but don't know. See my setup:

**Dockerfiles**

*- web*

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Initialize
RUN mkdir -p /data/web
WORKDIR /data/web
COPY requirements.txt /data/web/

# Setup
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt


# Prepare
COPY . /data/web/
EXPOSE 8000
```

*- nginx*

```
FROM nginx

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install openssl -y
RUN mkdir -p /etc/letsencrypt/archive/mydomain.org/
RUN mkdir -p /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.org/

COPY letsencrypt /etc/letsencrypt/archive/mydomain.org/

RUN ln -s /etc/letsencrypt/archive/mydomain.org/cert1.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.org/cert.pem
RUN ln -s /etc/letsencrypt/archive/mydomain.org/chain1.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.org/chain.pem
RUN ln -s /etc/letsencrypt/archive/mydomain.org/fullchain1.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.org/fullchain.pem
RUN ln -s /etc/letsencrypt/archive/mydomain.org/privkey1.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.org/privkey.pem


RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
```

redis and postgres come from offical images.

This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    restart: always
    build: ./web/
    links:
      - postgres:postgres
      - redis:redis
    env_file:
      - db.env
      - web_prod.env
    command: gunicorn turtle.wsgi:application -w 2 -b :8000
    volumes:
      - /data/web
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis

  nginx:
    restart: always
    build: ./nginx_prod/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes_from:
      - web
    volumes:
      - /var/log/nginx
    links:
      - web:web

  postgres:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - db.env
    expose:
      - "5432"

  redis:
    restart: always
    image: redis:latest
    expose:
      - "6379"
```

Thereby, I load some variables to share DB credentials and set some django setting values like DEBUG=0, SECRET_KEY etc.

This is my nginx config:

```
worker_processes 1;
pid /tmp/nginx.pid;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    accept_mutex off;
}

http {
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    sendfile on;

    upstream web {
        server web:8000 fail_timeout=0;
    }

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        return 444;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        charset utf-8;

        server_name mydomain.org www.mydomain.org;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name mydomain.org www.mydomain.org;
        keepalive_timeout 5;

        location / {
            try_files %uri @proxy_to_app;
        }

        location @proxy_to_app {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://web;
        }

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.org/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.org/privkey.pem;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
        ssl_ciphers EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:EECDH:EDH:!MD5:!RC4:!LOW:!MEDIUM:!CAMELLIA:!ECDSA:!DES:!DSS:!3DES:!NULL;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/archive/mydomain.org/dhparam4096.pem;
        ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;

        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;

        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.org/chain.pem;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;

        ssl_session_timeout 10m;
        ssl_session_cache off;
        ssl_session_tickets on;
        ssl_session_ticket_key /etc/letsencrypt/archive/mydomain.org/nginx_ticketkey;
    }
}
```

Web container is crushing with following error message.

```
{"log":"[2017-08-29 17:16:59 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2017-08-29T17:16:59.198605099Z"}
{"log":"[2017-08-29 17:16:59 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (1)\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2017-08-29T17:16:59.199346576Z"}
{"log":"[2017-08-29 17:16:59 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2017-08-29T17:16:59.199357527Z"}
{"log":"[2017-08-29 17:16:59 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2017-08-29T17:16:59.202010346Z"}
{"log":"[2017-08-29 17:16:59 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2017-08-29T17:16:59.227037442Z"}
{"log":"[2017-08-29 17:16:59 +0000] [7] [ERROR] Exception in worker process\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2017-08-29T17:16:59.460028625Z"}
{"log":"Traceback (most recent call last):\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2017-08-29T17:16:59.460048425Z"}
{"log":"  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py\", line 578, in spawn_worker\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2017-08-29T17:16:59.460051755Z"}
{"log":"    worker.init_process()\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2017-08-29T17:16:59.460054822Z"}
{"log":"  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py\", line 126, in init_process\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2017-08-29T17:16:59.460057228Z"}
{"log":"    self.load_wsgi()\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2017-08-29T17:16:59.46005997Z"}
{"log":"  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py\", line 135, in load_wsgi\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2017-08-29T17:16:59.46006246Z"}
{"log":"    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2017-08-29T17:16:59.46006513Z"}
{"log":"  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py\", line 67, in wsgi\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2017-08-29T17:16:59.460067413Z"}
{"log":"    self.callable = self.load()\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2017-08-29T17:16:59.460069991Z"}
{"log":"  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py\", line 65, in load\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2017-08-29T17:16:59.460072224Z"}
{"log":"    return self.load_wsgiapp()\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2017-08-29T17:16:59.46007479Z"}
{"log":"  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py\", line 52, in load_wsgiapp\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2017-08-29T17:16:59.460077063Z"}
{"log":"    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2017-08-29T17:16:59.460079605Z"}
{"log":"  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py\", line 352, in import_app\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2017-08-29T17:16:59.460081902Z"}
{"log":"    __import__(module)\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2017-08-29T17:16:59.460084489Z"}
{"log":"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'turtle.wsgi'; 'turtle' is not a package\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2017-08-29T17:16:59.460086702Z"}
{"log":"[2017-08-29 17:16:59 +0000] [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2017-08-29T17:16:59.460089174Z"}
```

**Project Structure**

`web
 - app
 - static
 - staticfiles
 - turtle
  - __init__.py
  - settings.py
  - urls.py
  - wsgi.py
 - Dockerfile
 - manage.py`

Comment: Any logs to share?

Comment: This is the next problem, I enabled logs, however nginx is not writing anything into the error.log file. I used an EFS volume. Also the docker inspect command that resolves me the container error file on the host has no content. The error produced by "web" is completed in the orginial question.

Comment: The docker image python is not configured to use _tkinter. The turtle module is meant to be used on desktop computers, not servers. Tk is a gui library that is required by `turtle`. You have to remove your turtle code, or somehow emulate a desktop environment in your web server to run turtle.

Comment: You could try installing this alpine python3-tkinter package. Add it in the web `Dockerfile`. I suppose it would replace the `python3` apk package.

https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/x86/python3-tkinter 
But I think you still would need a real or emulated display on your server to use tkinter.

Comment: You could put something like that in your nginx configuration to direct errors to stdout: `error_log /dev/stdout info;` You can then setup the awslogs in your task definition to display them in Cloudwatch.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your help so far. First step I made is to go away from the alpine image and manually install python stuff. I now use the python docker image. I updated the original question regarding the web docker file. After doing this I faced a new issue, see the updated error text of web/gunicorn. Now gunicorn can't find the turtle.wgsi module. So I added my project structure to the original question, maybe this helps. I assume it is about path issues in production environment.

Comment: I changed the gunicorn command to: gunicorn --error-logfile gunicorn.log --chdir /data/web turtle.wsgi:application -w 2 -b :8000
However, the result is the same ...